# Why does basic Spring project use Spring Boot (STS)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring Tool Suite and learning Spring. I've created a Spring Start Project. The project wizard ask for the version of Boot.

I'm just practicing Spring and doing output to the console. Why do I need Spring Boot? There's not way to create a simple Spring project without it.

Comment: You do not need spring boot

Comment: you dont need it at all. But I would recommend to use it. Configuration is much easier than without.

Comment: Then how do I create a console app without Boot?

Comment: why you wont use boot? without using boot its not simpler.

Comment: What does Boot provide and why can't I get rid of it?

Comment: spring boot provides all the core spring features and many more. Spring boot just simplify creating spring applications at all. It uses autoconfiguration and there is no need for xml configuration anymore. You can do it in your java classes. I would say its the new standard and its not necessary anymore to create a normal spring application.

Comment: I would try a boot project and a non-boot project. Then choose what fits you better

Comment: @efekctive: "I would try a...non-boot project." yeah - ok, how?

Comment: STS-> new project-> Spring->Spring Legacy Project. That should tell you something. If you are learning Spring and it defaults to Boot that should be a hint to at least try

Comment: @efekctive: you just conflicted yourself.

Comment: No. I was trying to help you compare both without telling you what to do. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody forces you to use Spring Boot. It is probably the easiest and clearly the recommended way of using Spring nowadays, but nobody forces you.

Since it is the recommended way, we provide support for creating Spring projects using Spring Boot in STS and help you with that a lot, using the  [initializr](http://start.spring.io) in the background.

But if you want to use just the Spring core framework, you can create a Java Project yourself, choose a dependency management mechanism like Maven, and add the dependencies to the core Spring framework yourself. There is nothing that prevents you from doing that - and there are no dependencies from the core Spring framework that require Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Just a showcase for making an output to the console using spring boot.

Create a Spring-Starter Project like you already did. Use `jar` as packaging and no other spring dependency (you can add all your needed features later). So STS should create your application.

Spring-boot create one main class out of the box: `{projectName}Application.java`. It looks like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

you have already a running Spring application now.

For just make an output to the console, one possibility is to use `CommandLineRunner`. Just implement the interface and the overriden method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello Spring boot");

    }
}
```

Run the project using STS or commandline and see the output.

Comment: So I guess at the end of the day, if you use STS, you are forced to use Spring Boot? That's fine if that is how STS does it. I just want to know that is the only way.

Comment: Neither STS nor Spring forces you to use Spring Boot. Both assumptions are wrong...

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah your right, forces is not the correct word. It was more meant for the recommended way